# How to properly format a CSV using pandas

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON with multiple objects and dictionaries, my JSON is below:

```
{
   "lastMonth":{
    "totalCost":4120.6241,
   "cpu_avg_partition":{
     "10":{
        "count":1,
        "cost":0.0,
        "value":10
        "period":"lastMonth",
        "resourceTypes":{
            "db":{
                "cost":842.8003
```

and etc...... etc.

And I have Python pandas code as below where I converted to CSV file but not in expected format

Python code:

```
import json,ast
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas import compat

compat.PY3 = True

df=pd.read_json("monthly_costformatter_data.json")
new_df = df.transpose() 
column_name = new_df.columns.values
new_df[['totalCost','cpu_avg_partition','providers','period',
        'resourceTypes','accounts','running_hours_partition',
        'projects']].to_csv('test10pands.csv',index=True,encoding='utf-8')
```

And the output is as below in CSV file

```
                totalCost   cpu_avg_partition   providers   period  
  resourceTypes accounts    running_hours_partition projects
  currency_code GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP
  currentMonth  1769.9801   {u'10': {u'count': 0, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 
 10}, u'100': {u'count': 0, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 100}, u'5': {u'count': 
 10, 
  idmap                     {u'188f6226-59d8-4a7c-9fdb-f32f4f0885ff':  
 u'628455167342'}       {u'813': u'ACP PM Work'}
 lastMonth  4120.6241   {u'10': {u'count': 1, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 10}, 
 u'100': {u'count': 0, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 100}, u'5': {u'count': 16, 
u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 5}, u'50': {u'count': 0, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 50},
```

BUT I also removed the you unicode character using

Comment: Please properly intent your code.

Comment: I want to print the 10': {u'count': 0, u'cost': 0.0, u'value': 
 10}, separeate row and next values in separate row

Comment: @Rahulkp Done!!!

Comment: Why the `compat.PY3 = True`? That should **never** be needed. The constant is determined *by the module itself at runtime based on what Python interpreter you are using*, and should not be something you set manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I used Compat.PY3 = true and encode= utf-8  for knocking off the Unicode character u from getting printed without those lines it printed the character u

Comment: @jackson: That's not how this works, sorry. I suspect you want to re-encode the data to JSON, you now have a Python datastructure representation in your columns. Not familiar enough with Pandas to make that a full answer however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Is there any other lib that i can use for structerd and looped json into csv using python

Comment: May I see output of `df.head()`.

Comment: @stovfl, pls see the output:
 totalCost cpu_avg_partition providers period resourceTypes accounts running_hours_partition projects
currency_code GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP GBP
currentMonth 1769.9801 {'10': {'count': 0, 'cost': 0.0, 'value': 10}, '100': {'count': 0, 'cost': 0.0, 'value': 100}, '5': {'count': 10, 'cost': 0.0, 'value': 5}, '50': {'count': 0, 'cost': 0.0, 'value': 50}, '90': {'count': 0, 'cost': 0.0, 'value': 90}} {'azure': {'cost': 756.614}, 'aws': {'cost':

Comment: @jackson: This is **not** the output of `df.head()`!